# Store Two Text Fields to Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two input fields, one asking for the users email and the other asking for the users city. Once the user clicks on the submit button I want to store that information in a child on Firebase under "potentialCities". I know how to send this information to the database with one field, but I can't get it to send the two fields.

My form:

[image]

HTML Form:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    <input type="email" id="userCityEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
    <input type="text" id="cityTextField" placeholder="City">
    <button id="citySubmitButton" onclick="submitCityClick(); return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS File:

```
var userCityEmail = document.getElementById('userCityEmail');
var cityTextField = document.getElementById('cityTextField');
var citySubmitButton = document.getElementById('citySubmitButton');

function submitCityClick() {
  var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
  var userEmail = userCityEmail.value;
  var userCity = cityTextField.value;

  firebaseRef.child("potentialCities").push().set(userEmail).set(userCity);
}
```

When I click the button nothing is sent to the Firebase database. My question is, whats the best way to send the information from two text fields to one child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if its the best, most efficient way to store the values, but I was able to get the end resulted I wanted by doing the following:

```
var userCityEmail = document.getElementById('userCityEmail');
var cityTextField = document.getElementById('cityTextField');
var citySubmitButton = document.getElementById('citySubmitButton');

function submitCityClick() {
  var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
  var userEmail = userCityEmail.value + " " + cityTextField.value;

  firebaseRef.child("potentialCities").push().set(userEmail);
}
```

So all I did was catenate the two values into one variable.

Answer (score 0):

If `email`, `city` are already **keys** in your firebase, All you can do is setting the *values* to those particular *keys*:

```
firebaseRef.push().set({
  city: userCity ,
  email: userEmail 
});
```